# How to append Excel tab name as an ID column in final dataframe R

Tags: r, excel, import

I use the following code to import multiple tabs from a single excel sheet. The name of the resulting df is the same as the name of the tab. So if in the excel sheet, there's a tab named "a" we get a resultant df "a" in R with its contents.

```
sheetnames <- readxl::excel_sheets(raw.data.dir)

mylist <- lapply(readxl::excel_sheets(raw.data.dir), readxl::read_excel, path = raw.data.dir)

# name the dataframes
names(mylist) <- sheetnames
# Bring the dataframes to the global environment
list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
```

Is it possible to add a column to the resultant DF that is filled in with the name of the tab/sheet?

Reproducible example

```
a = data.frame(
  y1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  y2 = c(4, 5, 6)
)
 
b = data.frame(
  y1 = c(7, 8, 9),
  y2 = c(1, 4, 6)
)
 
sheetnames <- c("a","b")

mylist = list(a, b)

names(mylist) <- sheetnames

list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
```

This returns df a:

```
   y1    y2
1  1     4
2  2     5 
3  3     6
```

I've then been manually appending the name to the df, but would like to automate it to get this:

```
   y1    y2   id
1  1     4    a
2  2     5    a
3  3     6    a
```

But I want it to look like this:

Answer (score -1):

Using `Map` you could do:

```r
mylist <- Map(function(x, y) transform(x, id = y), mylist, names(mylist))

list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

a
#>   y1 y2 id
#> 1  1  4  a
#> 2  2  5  a
#> 3  3  6  a

b
#>   y1 y2 id
#> 1  7  1  b
#> 2  8  4  b
#> 3  9  6  b
```